Does adding a new user as owner of firebase project and removing the previous owner affect the project?
I am currently working on a React Native project and I set up the Firebase project on my main Gmail account. Now, there were some issues in my main account and I also wanted more security so I created a new Gmail account and added the new Gmail account as a user in Firebase and made him owner.
Now, I want to remove the original previous Gmail account as a user/owner from the project. Does it affect the project in any sense, like the database or authentication if the previous user is completely removed from the ownership?
I expect to give the new Gmail account full control and access to the Firebase project and everything should work seamlessly without any issue, but I am not sure if it will cause any trouble.


Now, I want to remove the original previous Gmail account as a user/owner from the project.

When you add a new user as an owner and remove your personal account, it means that you're basically transferring the ownership of your Firebase project. This means the new owner will have full administrative privileges.

Does it affect the project in any sense, like the database or authentication if the previous user is completely removed from the ownership?

No, removing the previous owner will not affect your project's functionality, such as the Firebase Authentication or access to the databases (Firestore or the Realtime Database). So if you're worried about the the products that are active in your project, please note that the databases and authentication will remain intact.
There is however something that you take into consideration before transferring the ownership. If there are some linked services, billing accounts, or APIs in the Google Cloud Console that are active, please make sure they are also active in the new account as an admin or owner. Since a Firebase project is a Google Cloud project, meaning that the Firebase project is part of a Google Cloud project with linked services, also verify access in the Google Cloud Console.
